# Удаляются ли SharePref при обновлении приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Я храню переменную в `SharePref` которая при запуске приложения проверяет юзер уже залогинен или нет(своего рода флаг) и в зависимости от этого открывает либо основной экран либо предлагает регистрацию.

Так вот, что я думаю... при обновлении приложения новой версии допустим через плей маркет, файл с префами удаляется или нет?

Comment: Этот же вопрос на английском, с ответом: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12637737/2076787

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, файл не удалится. Но юзер может удалить его вручную через очистку данных приложения.

Comment: И лучше предупреждать юзеров, а то они такие :D

Comment: @iFr0z А как предупреждать юзера?

Comment: Так я ставлю модификатор доступа приватный... Юзер все равно может его удалить? Я помню просто когда хотел найти этот файл где он находится, у меня так и не получилось и вроде как причина была в том, что стоит приватный модификатор... А что часто бывает, что юзер залазиет в системные папки и специально ищет, что там удалить?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko когда войти в настройки приложения, там есть стереть кэш, стереть данные все

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да как угодно можно предупреждать через toast или диалоговое окно.

Comment: @iFr0z Чет я слабо себе представояю как это должно выглядеть... Юзер закончил регистрацию и тут ему диалоговое окно с текстом "Только не заходите в настройки приложения и не стирайте там кэш"... Ну ок, может вы знаете как это реализовано в больших приложениях? к примеру facebook? Как они понимают, что этот юзер уже залогинился?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko можно туториал по приложухе сделать и там это написать)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko либо сделайте в настройках своего приложения кнопку очистка данных и когда он на нее нажмет, то выведите предупреждение с кнопками "ок", "отмена"

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, помешать юзеру вы не сможете в деле очисти данных. Предупредить его можно где угодно и как угодно, хоть в маркете. Всё одно найдутся те, кто скажет, что этого не ввидел. Ну и юзер обычно представляет что может произойти при очиске данных приложения.

Comment: @iFr0z хаха)) представил туториал по приложухе)) Ну и все же как это реализовано в больших приложениях? есть догадки? Вот не помню, чтоб где то в facebook или контакте в настройках было очистить кэш... Может мне просто не попадалось... Но и делать это в настройках тоже не пойму зачем? Вот сколько лет у меня телефон ни разу не было, чтоб мне захотелось зайти в папку приложения и удалить кэш. Или есть такие люди?))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну тут я согласен, даже если найдутся такие которые любят удалять кеш то они должны понимать, что возможно что то нужно будет поправить потом...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, очистка данных приложения - один из самых частых и реально работающих советов при неполадках в приложении. Многие баги гугловых приложений лечатся именно так. Так что такие люди есть, их много и они часто знают, что данное действие может сбросить в т.ч. авторизованность в приложении.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, например в приложении для ВКонтакта очистка данных разлогинивает юзера.